# Not able to link iOS App with Google AdMob

Tags: ios, admob

I have published my app on the App Store 2 days ago but, on the Google AdMob I can't link my App as it says it will take a few days before it is showed up on the the list at Google AdMob. I wanted to ask whether I can still distribute my app to people and still see the ad analytics. Or will it affect the my ad earnings if I don't link it with my iOS app? Also it won't lead to blocking of my Google AdMob account right? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

New iOS apps will not show Google ads until they’re listed in the Apple App Store. [Link.](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en-GB) I've received the error "No ad to show from all configured ad networks" before my app was linked. To link your iOS app:

1. Login to [AdMob](https://admob.google.com/home/)
2. Click your app
3. Navigate to App Settings
4. Click 'Add' on App Store
5. Search for your published app and select

In some cases, the newly added app will take a couple of days before Google has crawled the app store and added it to the list of published apps to select. Be patient!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my iOS app had been released about 4 weeks and still I couldn't link the app to my AdMob account. I have to contact the [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk) and they quickly fixed the issue for me. Now everything works!

**Tip**: If you didn't find your app by the name, try the following options:

- the app's AppStore URL, for example: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spotify-discover-new-music/id324684580
- the app's store ID, for example: `id324684580`
- the publisher name, for example: `Spotify Ltd.`